# Get current github branch name in heroku deploy

Tags: git, github, heroku

Is there a way to detect the currently deploying github branch during a deploy/build? Or in the app while the dyno is running. So far I have tried:

- `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` but it is not a git repo so this fails
- ENV variables, `printenv` doesn't show me any variable that corresponds to the git branch

The only other thing I can think of is calling the github deployments API but this seems very long winded. Heroku must be storing this information somewhere accessible their end.

Comment: We already have runtime-dyno-metadata labs feature enabled and that doesn't include it

Answer (score 1):

Response from Heroku support:

> Unfortunately the git branch is not something we expose to the
>   application.
>
> I've created a feature request to pass this request on to the product
>   team.
>
> I have seen some apps connect to GitHub to grab additional commit
>   details as needed, but the specifics will depend on your workflow.